# Downwards arrows in forest

Tags: forest

I have the following tree and want the connections between nodes to be arrows rather than plain lines. Is this possible? I found the `edge` option, but this does not provide an appropriate option.

```
\documentclass{article}                          


\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}, 
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}}
}



\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
sn edges
[D-Struktur 
  [S-Struktur
        [Tilgungsregeln{,}\\Filter{,} phonol. Regeln
                [Phonetische\\Form (PF)]]
        [Regeln des anaphorischen Bezugs{,}\\der Quantifizierung und der Kontrolle
                [Logische\\Form (LF)]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `edge` option to indicate which kind of line between nodes do you need.

```
edge={->}
```

would be the easiest. You have an example `forest` documentation page 19.

```
\documentclass{article}                          

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,edge={->},base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}, 
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}}
}



\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
sn edges
[D-Struktur 
  [S-Struktur
        [Tilgungsregeln{,}\\Filter{,} phonol. Regeln
                [Phonetische\\Form (PF)]]
        [Regeln des anaphorischen Bezugs{,}\\der Quantifizierung und der Kontrolle
                [Logische\\Form (LF)]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since I see this 'forest' package for the first time, I was just wondering...is it also possible to create trees horizontally using this?

Comment: Yes, see the documentation.

Comment: @Ignasi How would it be possible to have an arrow (or arrows) manually? (Say, at a specific edge only.)