# To draw a hierarchy tree diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

i am new to latex. how can i make a hierarchy tree diagram as shown below?[image]

Comment: Could you send us some attempt of [what you've tried](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)?

Comment: For arrow heads see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187565

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Updated answer (current Forest)

This version uses the `edges` library. If you get errors, use the code below or, preferably, update your TeX installation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
    l sep'+=10pt,
    fork sep'=10pt,
  },
  forked edges,
  if level=0{
    inner xsep=0pt,
    tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
  }{},
  [Angiography Based On Medical Imaging Modalities
    [Biplane\\X-Ray/DSA]
    [Magnetic\\Resonance
      [Contrast Enhanced]
      [Non-Contrast Enhanced
        [Time of Flight]
        [Black-Blood]
        [Phase Contrast]
        [T2]
        [T2\textsuperscript{*}]
      ]
    ]
    [Computed-\\Tomography, calign with current]
    [Ultrasound]
    [Fusion of\\Modalities]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: with current Forest]

## Original answer

A slightly different `forest` solution which uses `tikz` to draw the line under the root. This also lines things up in a way which I think is neater than shown in the target image but, obviously, tastes differ so your kilometres may vary.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
    l sep+=10pt,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    if level=0{
      inner xsep=0pt,
      tikz={\draw [thick] (.south east) -- (.south west);}
    }{}
  }
  [Angiography Based On Medical Imaging Modalities
    [Biplane\\X-Ray/DSA]
    [Magnetic\\Resonance
      [Contrast Enhanced]
      [Non-Contrast Enhanced
        [Time of Flight]
        [Black-Blood]
        [Phase Contrast]
        [T2]
        [T2\textsuperscript{*}]
      ]
    ]
    [Computed-\\Tomography, calign with current]
    [Ultrasound]
    [Fusion of\\Modalities]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz underlining]

Comment: Is it possible to remove the underline under the `Angiography Based On Medical Imaging Modalities`?

Comment: @alper Just remove the `if level=0{...}{}` bit

Answer (score 8):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={%
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-12pt)-| (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
}
[
\underline{A}, calign=child,calign child=3
[B]
[M
[C]
[N
[T]
[B]
[P]
[T2]
[T2*]
]
]
[C]
[U]
[F]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that things like `\forestOve`, `\forestove` etc. should not be used. These are internal macros, which the package author has asked not be used. There are end-user equivalents which can be used instead are are much less likely to break. Basically, you're using stuff the author regards as fair game in any update, because you're not meant to use them in the first place. I probably didn't know this when I upvoted this originally or I'd not have done it.

Answer (score 7):

Such diagrams can be made with `tikz-qtree` (among others):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,ulem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=40pt]
  \tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,->, 
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
  \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center}}
  \tikzset{every level 1 node/.style={font=\small, text width=2cm}}
  \tikzset{every level 2 node/.style={font=\small, text width=4cm}}

  \Tree [.{\uline{Angiography Based On Medical Imaging Modalities}}
    [.{Biplane\\X-ray/DSA} ]
    [.{Magnetic\\Resonance} [.{Contrast Enhanced} ]
                            [.{Non-Contrast Enhanced} [.{Time of Flight} ]
                                                      [.{Phase Contrast} ] ]]
    [.{Computed-\\Tomography} ]
    [.{Ultrasound} ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```