# How to draw tree scheme?

Tags: tikz-trees, graphs

I am writing the report for my lesson with the details like that. I would like to draw by tikz or anything else?

I really have no idea. I've taken a look but I didn't find out anything that could help me. So I hope you can help me.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do this with forest, Ti*k*Z or pstricks, or even without. But I am not sure if anybody will be eager to type up the stuff from your screen shot. Why don't you help yourself and others by punching the contents of the three boxes in? You merely post a preamble and something that has only an `\end{document}` but not `\begin{document}`. This kills the motivation to look at this in many of us.

Comment: Also, there are quite a lot of examples of trees similar to this on this site, so it isn't clear why you can't make at least a start on this, even if you are stuck on particular bits of it. You've tagged it `tikz-trees` and `graphs`. Those are good starts. `trees`, `tikz-qtree` and `forest` are other tags for trees. (I can't remember if there's one specifically for `pstricks` trees or not.) Or look at texample.net.

Comment: here my answer, thanks a lot

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256736/to-draw-a-hierarchy-tree-diagram

Comment: I should probably update my answer there to use the `edges` library ....

Comment: I've updated my answer to that question, in case you are using it.