# Draw a particular hierarchy tree diagram with a connector of the before to last level to the last one

Tags: diagrams, forest, trees

I use the code found here [To draw a hierarchy tree diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256736/to-draw-a-hierarchy-tree-diagram)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
    l sep'+=10pt,
    fork sep'=10pt,
  },
  forked edges,
  if level=0{
    inner xsep=0pt,
    tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
  }{},
  [Angiography Based On Medical Imaging Modalities
    [Biplane\\X-Ray/DSA]
    [Magnetic\\Resonance
      [Contrast Enhanced]
      [Non-Contrast Enhanced
        [Time of Flight]
        [Black-Blood]
        [Phase Contrast]
        [T2]
        [T2\textsuperscript{*}]
      ]
    ]
    [Computed-\\Tomography, calign with current]
    [Ultrasound]
    [Fusion of\\Modalities]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

How should I modify the code to get a result as follows

[image]

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

MWE to create the first three levels:

```
\documentclass[tikz,french]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        align=center,
        font=\sffamily,
        edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
        l sep'+=10pt,
        fork sep'=10pt,
    },
    forked edges,
    if level=0{
        inner xsep=0pt,
        tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
    }{},
    [{\bf Question:} Quels sont les facteurs contribuant à des taux d'échec\\élevés en cours de mécanique de première année?
    [Qu'est-ce\\qui a déjà\\été fait?
    [Revue de\\littérature]
    ]
    [Cours typique\\en mécanique\\de 1e année?
    [``Benchmarking''\\de cours]
    ]
    [Sujets\\probléma-\\tiques?
    [Analyser\\ le travail\\
    des étudiants]
    ]
    [Où le problème\\pourrait-il\\commencer?
    [Analyser\\le dossier\\
    universitaire]
    ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I cannot figure out how to include the fourth level emanating from the third level (enumeration starting from above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structures of the diagrams are very different, but if you want to draw the boundaries and have the nodes all the same height (at level 1), you might just add
    draw,
      where level=1{minimum height=8ex,anchor=north}{},

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={draw,
  where level=1{minimum height=8ex,anchor=north}{},
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
    l sep'+=10pt,
    fork sep'=10pt,
  },
  forked edges,
  if level=0{
    inner xsep=0pt,
    tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
  }{},
  [Angiography Based On Medical Imaging Modalities
    [Biplane\\X-Ray/DSA]
    [Magnetic\\Resonance
      [Contrast Enhanced]
      [Non-Contrast Enhanced
        [Time of Flight]
        [Black-Blood]
        [Phase Contrast]
        [T2]
        [T2\textsuperscript{*}]
      ]
    ]
    [Computed-\\Tomography, calign with current]
    [Ultrasound]
    [Fusion of\\Modalities]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or just add an empty line in the `Ultrasound` node

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={draw,
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
    l sep'+=10pt,
    fork sep'=10pt,
  },
  forked edges,
  if level=0{
    inner xsep=0pt,
    tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
  }{},
  [Angiography Based On Medical Imaging Modalities
    [Biplane\\X-Ray/DSA]
    [Magnetic\\Resonance
      [Contrast Enhanced]
      [Non-Contrast Enhanced
        [Time of Flight]
        [Black-Blood]
        [Phase Contrast]
        [T2]
        [T2\textsuperscript{*}]
      ]
    ]
    [Computed-\\Tomography, calign with current]
    [Ultrasound\\~]
    [Fusion of\\Modalities]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your addendum to the question:

```
 \documentclass[tikz,french]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        align=center,
        font=\sffamily,
        edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
        l sep'+=10pt,
        fork sep'=10pt,
    },
    forked edges,
    if level=0{
        inner xsep=0pt,
        tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
    }{},
    [{\bf Question:} Quels sont les facteurs contribuant à des taux d'échec\\élevés en cours de mécanique de première année?
    [Qu'est-ce\\qui a déjà\\été fait?
    [Revue de\\littérature,alias=A1]
    ]
    [Cours typique\\en mécanique\\de 1e année?
    [``Benchmarking''\\de cours,alias=A2]
    ]
    [Sujets\\probléma-\\tiques?
    [Analyser\\ le travail\\
    des étudiants,alias=A3]
    ]
    [Où le problème\\pourrait-il\\commencer?
    [Analyser\\le dossier\\
    universitaire,alias=A4]
    ]
    ]
\path (A3.south) -- (A2|-A3.south) coordinate[midway,below=10pt] (aux);
\node[anchor=north,below=15pt of aux] (D) {Dimitris};   
\foreach \X in {1,...,4}
{\draw[thick, -{Stealth[]}] (A\X) |- (aux) -- (D);}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have provided a MWE that creates the first three levels of the desired image but I cannot figure out how to include the fourth level.

Comment: @Dimitris I added a proposal.

Comment: THANKS A LOT. (Merci beaucoup:-)!). So If I combine your original solution with the new one I can a perfect result! I will try to make it on my own.

Comment: Ok. It was easy. I just need to add draw:-)! Thanks again. Just one last question. How to put Dimitris inside a rectangle?

Comment: @Dimitris Add `draw`: `\node[draw,anchor=north,below=15pt of aux] (D) {Dimitris};`

Comment: I am almost there:-)! It's just perfect. `  where level=1{minimum height=8ex,anchor=north}{}` gives a constant height in the first level. For the 2nd level how can I achieve the same height?

Comment: Ok; I figured out. Trivial. The difficult part was what you did. Thanks again!