# Change alignment of tree-boxes in Block Diagram using Forest package (or otherwise)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, forest, trees

I need to draw a tree-like diagram for a classification purpose. Getting a cue from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488621/162028), I came up with the following MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[tmargin=2in, bmargin=2in, lmargin=1.5in, rmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{usual metric on R}
        \item \label{usual metric on C}
        \item \label{usual metric on R2}
        \item \label{5}
        \item \label{6}
        \item \label{16}
        \item \label{17}
        \item \label{C_int}
        \item \label{C_sup}
        \item \label{norm}
        \item \label{extended R}
        \item \label{extended C}
        \item \label{discrete}
        \item \label{d/(1+d)}
        \item \label{product metric}
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={draw,
                where level=1{minimum height=8ex,anchor=north}{},
                align=center,
                %           font=\sffamily,
                edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
                l sep'+=10pt,
                fork sep'=10pt,
            },
            forked edges,
            if level=0{
                inner xsep=0pt,
                tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
            }{},
            [
            \qquad Examples of metric spaces in this subsection \qquad
            [
            \Cref{usual metric on R,usual metric on C,usual metric on R2,5,6,16,17,C_int,C_sup,norm}:\\
            Normed Linear Spaces
            [
            \Cref{usual metric on R,usual metric on C,usual metric on R2,5,6}:\\
            Finite dimensional\\ vector spaces
            [\Cref{5,6}:\\ $ p $ metric and\\ \emph{sup} metric on $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $]
            [\Cref{usual metric on R,usual metric on C,usual metric on R2}:\\ usual metrics on \\ $ \mathbb{R} $\text{,} $ \mathbb{C} $ and $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $]
            ]
            [
            \Cref{16,17}:\\ Sequence spaces
            ]
            [
            \Cref{C_int,C_sup}:\\ Spaces of continuous \\ functions
            ]
            ]
            [
            \Cref{extended R,extended C}:\\ Extended set of real\\ and complex numbers
            ]
            [
            \Cref{discrete}:\\ Discrete metric
            ]
            [
            \Cref{d/(1+d),product metric}:\\ Derived metrics
            ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
        \caption{Examples of metric spaces in this subsection}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What I am looking for is to fit the diagram within the margin. For that, I want to left-align the boxes in the third and fourth level. Something like this:

[image]

How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**

To add more alternatives to achieve my goal, please consider the following options:

1. the solution need not be using `forest` environment only. Any other way of giving the desired output is also welcome.
2. In case it is easier, the following output also works for me as well:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Normally you should be able to fix the problems by adding some suitable `text width`. However, this does not seem to work with the lengthy `\Cref`s you are using. (I am also wondering why you load `varioref`.)

Comment: I added `varioref` because I am using that package in my original document and I thought it would have some influence so I added in the MWE. I came across the `forest` package today itself to do this and Do not have much idea about how it works. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I definitely like the way it is showing the cross-references (I also have `hyperref` package installed in the original document) now, but an answer removing those packages would also work for me. I will insert the `\Cref` strings manually in that case.

Comment: I am definitely not suggesting to drop `forest` or `cleveref`, I just said what I tried and didn't work.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, please have a look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is more an extended comment than a real answer. I tried to control the nodes via `text width`, and failed. Almost certainly I did something stupid. Just in case there is really a problem with `text width`, here is something that installs an equivalent style, and works.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[tmargin=2in, bmargin=2in, lmargin=1.5in, rmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{usual metric on R}
        \item \label{usual metric on C}
        \item \label{usual metric on R2}
        \item \label{5}
        \item \label{6}
        \item \label{16}
        \item \label{17}
        \item \label{C_int}
        \item \label{C_sup}
        \item \label{norm}
        \item \label{extended R}
        \item \label{extended C}
        \item \label{discrete}
        \item \label{d/(1+d)}
        \item \label{product metric}
    \end{enumerate}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{5em}\centering
\Cref{usual metric on R,usual metric on C,usual metric on R2,5,6,16,17,C_int,C_sup,norm}:\\
Normed Linear Spaces
\end{minipage}}    
    
\begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
            forked edges,
            for tree={draw,l sep'+=10pt,minimum height=8ex,anchor=north,
                where level=1{anchor=north,l sep+=1.5em}{},
                where level=2{fork sep=4.2em,calign=first}{fork sep=10pt},    
                where level=0{}{execute at begin node={\begin{minipage}{6em}\centering},
                execute at end node={\end{minipage}}},
                %           font=\sffamily,
                edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},                                
            },
            [Examples of metric spaces in this subsection,text width=21em
            [%
            \Cref{usual metric on R,usual metric on C,usual metric on R2,5,6,16,17,C_int,C_sup,norm}:\\
            Normed Linear Spaces
            [%
            \Cref{usual metric on R,usual metric on C,usual metric on R2,5,6}:\\
            Finite dimensional\\ vector spaces
            [\Cref{5,6}:\\ $ p $ metric and\\ \emph{sup} metric on $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $]
            [\Cref{usual metric on R,usual metric on C,usual metric on R2}:\\ usual metrics on \\ $ \mathbb{R} $\text{,} $ \mathbb{C} $ and $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $]
            ]
            [%
            \Cref{16,17}:\\ Sequence spaces
            ]
            [%
            \Cref{C_int,C_sup}:\\ Spaces of continuous \\ functions
            ]
            ]
            [%
            \Cref{extended R,extended C}:\\ Extended set of real\\ and complex numbers
            ]
            [%
            \Cref{discrete}:\\ Discrete metric
            ]
            [%
            \Cref{d/(1+d),product metric}:\\ Derived metrics
            ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
        \caption{Examples of metric spaces in this subsection.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Taking a cue from your answer, I added `calign=first` to my code. [This](https://pastebin.com/raw/kbNrRDz8) is the final code for the `figure` and [this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnNh_584BiIjgslRMq2Mc1QpvgOr9A?e=Jpbe9h) is how it looks now.